# Angular: capture an event emmited inside a dynamic container

Tags: angular, eventemitter, angular-dynamic-components

I don't know if the title of the question is up to the challenge, but I'm trying to capture an event(click) issued by a dynamic component. My goal is to create a component onClick and destroy it by the same means. I actually manage to accomplish that, but with both buttons in the parent (creator and destroyer) component

The parent component TS:

```
listUsers: User;
 @ViewChild('listUsers',{read: ViewContainerRef, static:false}) usersContainer;
 componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;


createComponent(){
    this.usersContainer.clear();
    const factory: ComponentFactory<any> = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(DynamicComponent);
    this.componentRef = this.usersContainer.createComponent(factory);
    this.componentRef.instance.listUsers = this.listUsers;
  }

  closeList(event){
      console.log(event)  //  this.componentRef.destroy();
  }
```

Parent HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="createComponent()">List users</button>

<template #listUsers>
    <app-dynamic (closeList)="closeList($event)"></app-dynamic>

</template>
```

Dynamic TS:

```
export class DynamicComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() listUsers: User;
  @Output() closeList = new EventEmitter<any>()
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.listUsers)
  }
  close() {
    this.closeList.emit();
  }
}
```

Dynamic HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col md-6 offset-md-3">
            <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let u of listUsers">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    {{u.username}}
                </li>
            </ul>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="close()">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make this work? How can I get the reference of the template so I can tell parent component the emmited event is inside those tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just subscribe to the `EventEmitter` (it inherits `Observable`):

```
this.componentRef.instance.closeList.subscribe(() => this.componentRef.destroy());
```

Comment: ok, but do I do this subscription inside of the closeList method?

Comment: no you do it just after instantiating the dynamic component after this line `this.componentRef.instance.listUsers = this.listUsers;`